# standard and custom keyboard shortcut for terminal not working, every other shortcut continues to work. Ubuntu 17.10 w/ GNOME

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, terminator, virtual-console

I like to use <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to open up a terminal.  I set that in the keyboard shortcuts setting to open a terminal.  It works immediately after I set it, but after some time, or a logout it stops working.   The shortcut to open a browser that I set to <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> continues to work.

So after a couple of times of doing this, I set up a custom shortcut to run the command `terminator` set up as <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> and disabled the built in terminal shortcut.  Again this worked for a bit, but stopped when I logged out.  At the same time I made a custom keyboard shortcut for terminator I made one to run atom,  this one continues to work after the terminal shortcut stops.

In short:
terminal shortcut(s) stop working, every other keyboard shortcut continues to work.

How do I fix this?